# Issue in XML Parsing through Java

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing, normalization

I have the following simple XML structure that has to be parsed:

> ```
> <Nodes>
>   <Node id="1">
>       <att1>
>       <att2>
>       ...
>   </Node>
>   <Node id="2">
>       ...
> </Nodes>
> ```

Now the problem is simple that while parsing this file through Java code I am receiving the "line returns" as seperate nodes which is causing complexity in the processing ... I am even using the normalize method for DOMParsers but it doesn't seem to work..
below is the parser code:

```
public LogParser(File XMLFile) throws ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException, IOException {
    //Logger.printInfoMessage("XML file to be parsed is "+XMLFile.toString());
     DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = getDocumentBuilder();
    doc = documentBuilder.parse(XMLFile);
    doc.normalizeDocument();

}
```

Comment: Try this link http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Comment: @brettw - your preference has been noted.

Comment: The line feeds ans white space are represented as Text Nodes.  This is correct behavior.

Comment: @nitind- yes that is the correct behaviour but isn't it useless to represent line feeds and white spaces as Text Nodes hindering the basic purpose of parsing... :-( do we have a walk around for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `normalizeDocument()` normalizes based on the normalization options that you have previously specified .... and you haven't specified any.

I haven't read it in detail, but [this page](http://www.freeopenbook.com/xml-java/ch10lev1sec5.html) seems to explain how to deal with this.

It is worth noting that (according to the link above) not all XML parsers support this feature.